# Clear contents in column B to G for each row that has "remove" in column K

Tags: vba, excel

How can I clear the contents of column B to G for each row that has "remove" in column K.

**Example before running the code**
[image]

**After running the code**
[image]

**Here's my code but I'm not sure what to use to make it work**

```
Set rng = Range("K3", Range("K1000").End(xlUp))
For Each cel In rng
If cel.Value = "Remove" Then

'ClearContents in column B to G for each row that has Remove in column K

End If
Next cel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many statements you could use in that position of your code.  One might be:

```
cel.Offset(0, -9).Resize(1, 6).ClearContents
```

---

Another might be:

```
cel.EntireRow.Range("B1:G1").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 2):

Another:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(cel.Row,2),.Cells(cel.row,7)).ClearContents
End with
```

Comment: Not bad at all! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do it like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
     .Range(.Cells(cel.row,2),.Cells(cel.row,7)).clearcontents
end with
```

The refering of the Sheet would help you a bit to avoid some possible errors - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx